# Found opaque type error for matching types

Tags: rust

I am trying to get the following to compile:

```rust
use core::fmt::Debug;
use tokio::io::AsyncRead;
use tokio::io::AsyncWrite;
use core::cell::RefCell;
use futures::StreamExt;
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

struct State {
    foo: String
}

pub async fn test<A: AsyncWrite + AsyncRead + Unpin + Debug>(
    peers: &mut FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>>,
) {
    let mut pp: Vec<Rc<RefCell<(State, A)>>> = Vec::new();
    for p in pp {
        peers.push(async move {
            let p: (State, A) = p.into_inner();
            std::io::Result::Ok(p)
        });
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b0deddfdfcab08136afc202c9735f510)

But I am getting the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/lib.rs:17:20
    |
13  |       peers: &mut FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>>,
    |                                    ----------------------------------------------------------------- this type parameter
...
17  |           peers.push(async move {
    |  _______________----_^
    | |               |
    | |               arguments to this function are incorrect
18  | |             let p: (State, A) = p.into_inner();
19  | |             std::io::Result::Ok(p)
20  | |         });
    | |_________^ expected type parameter `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>`, found opaque type
    |
    = note: expected type parameter `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>` (type parameter `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>`)
                  found opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = Result<(State, A), std::io::Error>>` (opaque type at </rustc/897e37553bba8b42751c67658967889d11ecd120/library/core/src/future/mod.rs:72:43>)
    = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
    = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/bo
```

Why am I getting this? And how do I constrain the types to be the same here?

Comment: By typing with `impl` you're trying to constrain it to have all elements be the same closure defined inside the function, is that correct? That seems backwards to me: normally `impl` in a return value lets the function define the type implicitly, but in a parameter it lets *the function's caller* define the type. So you might be able to make it work if you instead created and returned `peers` in the function.

Comment: Replacing that `impl ...` with `Box<dyn ...>` or `Rc<dyn ...>` fixes that one error, but then others appear. Were you hoping for behavior like `dyn Trait`?

Comment: @DanGetz I want to add futures to `peers` inside the function `test`. I think I need to use `Box<dyn ...>` to make this work, but now I have the problem that the type parameter `A` needs to have `'static` lifetime: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3146df9084099624aa57867dc634be8e